# Windows Host Docker + WSL2 - How to mount Windows directory to a Linux container

Tags: linux, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Windows 10 as my host, and I am trying to mount a Windows directory into a Linux container (node, Debian based).

Previously, I was using Hyper-V backend and the dockerode package to interact with the Docker daemon to mount my Windows directory into my container. I could create a Docker volume by passing in a Driver opt lines of:

`device: /host_mnt/d/path/to/my/dir`

The keyword here being /host_mnt.

I am moving my development to using Docker dev containers and WSL2, however, the host_mnt path is no longer recognised. What is the correct path to mount a host Windows directory into my Linux container? I a running Docker Engine v20.10.3, Use the WSL 2 based engine is activated in my Docker settings and I am running Docker desktop 3.2.0 (61504).

Comment: I should say, through the Docker CLI, I can run:

docker run -v D:\Projects:/mnt/d -it python:3.8 /bin/bash

This works, and I can access my host machine. More specifically, I want to do this via the Docker daemon REST API.

Answer (score 2):

After some intense Googling / StackOverflowing, I found the magic incantation.

`/run/desktop/mnt/host/${driveLetter}/path/to/my/windows/dir`

Where ${driveLetter} is the drive letter in Windows but lower case (e.g. c, d, e, etc.)

Maybe I missed some documentation somewhere but now I can run my Node container on a Windows Host, and just mount my files from the Windows host directly into my container.

Edit:

Context:

My project is running a Node backend container, that has access to the Docker Daemon to spin up other containers. This container can spawn new containers (by making a call to the Docker daemon) and stop containers. Another responsibility is to mount some directories to the new containers.

We usually deploy on a Linux environment but for local development, we use Windows. So we don't usually care about this unless we're writing new code / debugging. We mount some local Windows directories into the new spawned container (which is what I wanted to do with the original question). Through Node and Dockerode, we make a call to the Docker Daemon to the create Container endpoint, with a HostConfig->Mounts->VolumeOptions->DriverConfig with the path in Windows.

Comment: Note that this is not recommended. You will get much better performance if you mount a folder that is actually in he Linux filesystem, rather than the Windows one.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you could add more context about how to use it (what file? what tool? is this the complete syntax you need?) so you don't need to be already familiar with WSL and Docker in order to understand it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @SiHa That is correct. We develop on a Windows platform but deploy on a Linux environment, so this was just to get it working for our local setup. If we were actually using Windows as our target platform, I would convert our setup to a Linux filesystem.

Regardless of the recommended answer, it was frustrating to not know the correct path to get WSL2 and Docker working without having to dig through lots of stackoverflow.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, apologies, I'll update the answer with some more details.

Comment: What if the folder you want to mount is not under /mnt/c but in the linux subsystem such as /home/justin ?